# How to fade out a message in jQuery on click

Tags: jquery, css

I am working in an application where I have to show a message on the successful  submission of something. In this working example this div is always showing, but I do not want that, I want it to be hidden and on click of a button the message should show. How can I achieve that? Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/VRYBk/1/

Here is the code also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".close-green").click(function () {
        $("#message-green").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    //fade out in 15 seconds if not closed 
    $("#message-green").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer that helped or worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, the `.click()` function doesn't bubble and hits the `<a href>` tag instead. Try binding it to the `<a>` instead of `<span>`.

Try giving a `.stop()` and then `fadeOut()` works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(".close-green").click(function () {
    $("#message-green").stop().fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
  });
  //fade out in 15 seconds if not closed 
  $("#message-green").delay(50000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
#message-green{
  height:30px;
  background:#00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message-green">Some Content <a href="#" class="close-green">Close</a></div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cj3L6Lr/**

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a delay to the animation queue on page load so any items added to that queue will get executed only after the delay.

You can clear the queue using [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close-green").click(function() {
    $("#message-green").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
  });

  //fade out in 15 seconds if not closed 
  $("#message-green").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");

});
```

```css
#message-green {
  height: 30px;
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message-green">
  Some Content
  <a href="#"><span class="close-green">Close</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the box to be hidden until you click the button, then show it until the timeout and then dissappear

Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRYBk/133/

To hide the message at the beginning:

```
#message-green{
    display:none;
}
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: seems to be, but i don't get it what other answers are saying because question's answer is this. **What OP has asked.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("#message-green").fadeIn("fast");
    //fade out in 15 seconds if not closed 
    $("#message-green").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
});

closeFN = function(){
     $("#message-green").css('display','none');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0n4chqhr/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this.

See my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/johnnynolan/wgxomxa0/1/).

```
$(".action-click").click(function () {
    $("#message-green").toggle("slow"); // toggles visibility
    $(this).toggle(); // toggles the trigger visibility
    $('#message-green').fadeOut(5000); // fades out message after 5s
});

// If the user clicks close before the auto Fadeout 
$('.close-green').click(function() {
    $('#message-green').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Basically, you could set the style of your div to `display:none;` and then fire a `toggle()` and then subsequent `fadeOut()` passing in the animation times as values such as 5000 for 5 seconds etc.

See the Jquery docs [here](http://jquery.com/), in particular the example code at the bottom regarding displaying of messages.

Finally, you might want to place all "Form" functionality into its own JS namespace and create functions there for handling it. Keep the inline JS to a minimum :)